# How to populate a dropdown list by previously selected item id

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8, textblock

I'm populating a dropdown with multiple values like productId, productName, skuId, Sku, and Category Id, and displaying with a dropdown using productName.

The data binding is from Webapi to dropdown.

Code:

```
this.productData = response.result;

<select id="prodcode" class="form-control" formControlName="prodCode"   required>
               <option [value]="''">Product Code</option>
               <option [ngValue]="product" *ngFor="let product of productData">
          {{product.productName}}
        </option>
     </select>
```

I can get product details from the `ng` value of product like this:

productName, skuId, Sku, Category Id.

While form editing I'm unable to populate the selected item in the dropdown list from a datatable. I wrote it like this:

```
 this.productForm.reset({
   prodCode: row.ProductId,
    qty: row.Quantity,
    mcp: row.MCP,
    weight: row.weight,
    rate: row.Rate
 )};
```

How can I populate the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

If `row` is a `product`, you should set it to `prodCode`.

```js
this.productForm.reset({
  prodCode: row,
   ty: row.Quantity,
)};
```

And I think the name of the variable should be changed to something like `product`.

Comment: zmag row contain no of values ..and product is object of ngvalue ..it contain productid ,skuid,sku,categoryid,product name ...i want populate previous selected item in edit mode

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign correct value to `[ngValue]` of `<options>`, for your above example, it will work when you use `[ngValue] = "product.productId"`(Check `this.productData` to see the if the capitalization and lowercase of `productId` are correct）

```
<select id="prodcode" class="form-control" formControlName="prodCode"   required>
           <option [value]="''">Product Code</option>
           <option [ngValue]="product.productId" *ngFor="let product of productData">
      {{product.productName}}
    </option>
 </select>
```